# defintion of weak solution

Tags: distribution-theory

i found that a weak solution of $-\Delta u=f $ where f $\in L^{2} (\Omega)$ is  a solution u $\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ and it is  solution in sense of distribution so what does it mean that that u  is solution in sense of distribution? is that for every $\phi$ in D($\Omega)$ we have $\langle\phi ,-\Delta u \rangle=\langle \phi ,f\rangle$? im right?
thanks

Comment: Rather $\langle -\Delta\phi , u \rangle=\langle \phi ,f\rangle$, but otherwise yes.

Comment: thank you Klaus but i dont understand what you mean do you mean that i write a mistake and the good answer is $\langle -\Delta \phi,u\rangle=\langle \phi,f\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, you want to apply the Laplacian to the test function because $u$ is not necessarily twice differentiable. That's the whole point of weak solutions/weak derivatives.